# Compare multiple values in two arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, nested, nested-loops

I have two MySQL Databases, and would like to compare the data using PHP variables. I connect to the databases and assign the variables using PDO:

```php
//Database 1
include_once('client-config.php');
try {
    $conn = new PDO(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE));
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$DB_Name = "pencuy204";
$login = $_SESSION['SESS_login'];
$qry = "SELECT `BetType`, `RiskAmount`, `WinAmount`, `BetDate`, `GameDate`, `BetRotation`, `TeamParticipant`, `MoneyLine`, `Spread`, `OverUnder`
        FROM `{$login}_bet`"; 
$result = $conn->query($qry);

// If the SQL query is succesfully performed ($result not false)
if ($result !== false) {
// Parse the result set, and adds each row and colums in HTML table
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $BetType[] = $row['BetType'];
        $BetRiskAmount[] = $row['RiskAmount'];
        $BetWinAmount[] = $row['WinAmount'];
        $BetGameDate[] = strtotime($row['GameDate']);
        $BetTeamParticipant[] = $row['TeamParticipant'];
        $BetMoneyLine[] = $row['MoneyLine'];
        $BetSpread[] = $row['Spread'];
        $BetOverUnder[] = $row['OverUnder'];
    }
}

//Database 2
try {
    require_once('bet-config.php'); 
    $conn1 = new PDO(B_DB_HOST, B_DB_USER, B_DB_PASSWORD);
    $conn1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}   

date_default_timezone_set('CST');
$today = date("Y-m-d"); 
$qry = "SELECT `AwayTeam`, `AwayScore`, `HomeTeam`, `HomeScore`, `FeedDate` FROM games";
$checkit = $conn1->query($qry);

if ($checkit !== false) {
    foreach($checkit as $row1) {
        $AwayTeam[] = $row1['AwayTeam'];
        $HomeTeam[] = $row1['HomeTeam'];
        $AwayScoreData[] = $row1['AwayScore'];
        $HomeScoreData[] = $row1['HomeScore'];
        $FeedDate[] = strtotime($row1['FeedDate']);
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is run through each value in certain PHP arrays in Database 1, comparing them every value in certain arrays in Database 2. Here is an example for loop that I am working on:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) { 
    foreach ($BetGameDate as $b) {
        if (($b == $FeedDate[$i])) {
            foreach ($BetTeamParticipant as $team) {
                if (($team == $AwayTeam[$i])) {
                    foreach ($BetType as $type) {
                        if (($type == "Money Line")) {
                            if ($AwayScoreData[$i] < $HomeScoreData[$i]) {
                                $BetV[] = "-" . $BetRiskAmount[$i];
                                $BetC[] = intval('$BetV');
                            }

                            if ($AwayScoreData[$i] > $HomeScoreData[$i]) {
                                $BetV[] = "+" . $BetWinAmount[$i];
                                $BetC[] = intval('$BetV');
                            }

                            if ($AwayScoreData[$i] == $HomeScoreData[$i]) {
                                $BetV[] = 0;
                                $BetC[] = intval('$BetV');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this particular example, if `$GameBetDate` is equal to `$FeedDate`, the bet team name is equal to the away team name, and the bet type is equal to a certain string, then compute the bet based on the risk amount or win amount for that specific bet(row) in database 1. I feel like my use of foreach is correct, but how can I properly use an iterated for loop to cycle through all of the values in database 2 against the specific values in database 1, and if the criteria matches, use values from database 1 to calculate `$BetC` and `BetV`?

Comment: Not a question. You may need to modify your topic to a real question like "How do I ...?" first.

Comment: First your code look so nasty to me I don't feel like reading it. Second be specific, don't write all of the code like connecting and everything else. Revise your question get better answers!

Comment: I agree with Ali and I have a second question.  Why do you have two databases?  I imagine it could be made much easier/faster if you would have a single database and let the database compare values.

Comment: How about use a join to do the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a little refactoring in your code.
To compare values you can use array_diff method.
You select the values from the first table, (PDO can return array)
Select second values and compare...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php